# How to publish a custom nuxt plugin + development workflow

Tags: plugins, nuxt.js

I am looking for some best practices for publishing and developing nuxt plugins. I would like to write a plugin which gives our web applications the possibility to request oauth tokens from everywhere. I have written this plugin localy in my project and it works. Now my target is to move the code to a seperate plugin project and upload it to npm so every one in my company might use it easily. Are there any guides how to setup a nuxt plugin project? I found several guides for creating vue-plugins but the structure of them are a bit different to nuxt. I do not have a install method. Because my plugin simply wraps vuex store methods defined in oAuthStore.js as global methods, which can be used when I register my plugin in nuxt.config.js. 
Vue plugins seems to work a bit different.

I upload a vue-plugin with an install method. When I try to import it and run my application on dev server (npm run dev) i always get the error message:

This dependency was not found:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  * my-plugin in ./plugins/vuex-persisted.js                                                                                                                                   friendly-errors 16:55:24
                                                                                                                                                                                 friendly-errors 16:55:24
To install it, you can run: npm install --save my-plugin

My plugin has been uploaded to npm correctly and I have used it by executing npm install --save my-plugin so it has an entry on dependency list in package.json.

When I try to npm-link my-plugin I get the same error. This is the only way I know for rapid prototyping because I do not want a npm publish every time I want to test something. Does everyone know a way for a better developing workflow for working on nuxt plugins?

Thanks for any help.

Best regards
Moritz

```
/** oAuthPlugin.js **/

import oAuthStore from './oAuthStore.js'
import Cookies from 'js-cookie'
import createPersistedState from 'vuex-persistedstate'

export default ({store, isHMR, app}, inject) => {

app.store.registerModule('oAuth', oAuthStore );

var me = app;

inject('getOAuthCredentials', () => {

    var data = {};

    if(app.$store) {

        var data = app.$store.getters["oAuth/getAuthCredentials"];
    }

    return data;
});

inject('requestOAuthCredentials', (data) => {

    if(me.store) {

        me.store.commit("oAuth/requestOAuthCredentials", data);
    }
});

if (isHMR) return
// add persisted state as a vue mounted mixin
if (!app.mixins) {
    app.mixins = []
}

app.mixins.push({mounted () {

    createPersistedState({
      key: 'vuex-persisted',
      paths: ['oAuth'],
      storage: {
        getItem: key => Cookies.get(key),
        setItem: (key, value) => Cookies.set(key, value, {expires: 3}),
        removeItem: key => Cookies.remove(key)
      }
    })(store);
  }});
}


/** nuxt.config.js **/

 /*
  ** Plugins to load before mounting the App
  */
 plugins: [
    { src: '~/plugins/vuex-persisted', ssr: false },
    { src: '~/plugins/oAuthPlugin.js' }
 ],
```